# Read network traffic from pcap file for SSL Inspection using mitmproxy

Tags: ssl, pcap, mitmproxy

I have a collection of TLS traffic in pcap file. I would like to decrypt and analyze the content of the traffic using mitmproxy. mimtproxy saves traffic in a custom [format](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-tools/#example-saving-traffic) and it can read back traffic from that file format. Is there a way in which I could make mitmproxy read traffic from pcap file or convert pcap files to mitmproxy file format? Or is there any other tool by which I could do that? Ideally, I want to perform SSL inspection in traffic from pcap file.

Comment: SO is about programming. If you have a problem with your code that tires to solve your problem, please share it. Advice on what tools to use is opinion and has no place on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Mitmproxy allows TLS decryption and the way required to decrypt an pcap dump that has been generated without Mitmproxy in between is totally different:

Mitmproxy only works if the traffic is intercepted so that the traffic is temporary decrypted available in Mitmproxy where as the pcap usually contains non-mitmproxy-intercepted traffic.

For decoding a TLS data from pcap you need the exported pre-master secret keys from the client or the server (or for SSL/TLS ciphers that don't use perfect forward privacy you can decrypt the traffic using the private server key).

For details of TLS decryption using Wireshark see https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS